# Как 4 предыдущих репозитория скопировать в один новый?

Tags: git

Мне  нужно выполнить задание:

у меня есть 4 репозитория
мне нужно будет повторить все 4 предыдущих,
используя только командную строку `MINGW64` (*в которой работает гит*).

- Вы не можете использовать:

  - файловый менеджеры,
  - текстовые редакторы с графическим интерфейсом, `gitk` / `git gui`.
- Вам разрешается использовать:

  - браузер только для операций с `github`.
  - Все остальное только через консоль.
    Это самая сложная задача в этом курсе.

Команды которые я могу использовать:

```
echo
cd
cat
vi
```

как сделать так чтоб 4 предыдущих репозитория скопировать в один новый?

Comment: что значит «скопировать в один» и «повторить все 4 предыдущих»?

Comment: @chaiz, [отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1436196/edit) ваш вопрос, покажите, что вы уже пробовали делать сами, с какой конкретной проблемой столкнулись? В таком виде вопрос будет закрыт, потому что этот сайт [не предназначен](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) для решения учебных задач.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос не очень понятен, предполагается наверно освоение инструментария для работы с гитом, но с помощью команд выше вряд ли описанные манипуляции можно сделать, наверно предполагается что еще команды гит имеются?

В любом случае

- `echo` - вывод информации на экран
- `cd` - смена текущей директории
- `cat` - создает, суммирует или показывает содержимое файла
- `vi` - текстовый редактор, можно освоить основы работы за пару часов если при установленном редакторе в используемом дистрибутиве ОС в терминале набрать `vimtutor` или `vimtutor ru`, команды вводятся через двоеточие, например `:q` для выхода из редактора.

Если нужна тренировка по работе с гитом, то можно пройти [тренажер](https://ru.hexlet.io/courses/intro_to_git) по работе как раз  гит с консолью и похожими заданиями + минимум по работе с [консолью](https://ru.hexlet.io/courses/cli-basics).